# How to use password authentication for BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create an iPhone and Android application that accesses a device with sensitive personal information, such as a body composition analyzer, via BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy).

At that time, it is problematic if anyone can read the device's information, so we are thinking of creating the following mechanism.

- Some users of the body composition analyzer will store their passwords and usernames in the device.
- Reading from the app via BLE is only possible if the username/password combination is correct

I know that if Bluetooth Classic is available, this can be done using SPP communication, but since SPP is not available from the iPhone, it must be done via BLE.

However, since BLE Peripheral data can be read by anyone with an app like nRF Connect during advertisements, is BLE not suitable for this kind of application?
Is it possible to create such an authentication system with BLE? If so, what kind of mechanism is possible?

Comment: Security over an open channel would depend upon the attack you are trying to mitigate. You can always encrypt/sign your BLE data at the cost of reduced bandwidth, i.e. two bytes of data for every three. Of course if someone hacks your app or bluetooth device the endpoints are compromised.

Answer (score 0):

If the pairing model and I/O capability requirements offered by standard BLE pairing does not fit for you, you will need to treat the BLE communication as a generic public (non secure) channel. On top of this you can put any type of generic security mechanism that fits your needs such as TLS or any PAKE.